# Saving all element states for OWN history?

Tags: jquery, back, forward

I have a visual editor wich uses normal drag&drop divs in a specific area.
Now i want to build or include an own history system, so that the user can click a back button (not the browser-button) and the last change is reversed.

For example: "Insert Modul B after A" -> "Delete Modul A" -> Back-Button -> (Modul A is back again.)

Is there a good jQuery-Plugin for that? Or how should i save states? (I think copy all HTML isnt the best solution).

Its hard to google for because i ever find plugins for the browser history..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds specific enough that you would have to program your own custom solution.